# ERC20 verification for arbitrary address

Tags: erc-20, bytecode

I'm trying to verify if an arbitrary contract complies ERC20. While doing so I'm checking if the contract code has the following markers:

```
totalSupply() - 18160ddd
balanceOf(address) - 70a08231
allowance(address,address) - dd62ed3e
transfer(address,uint256) - a9059cbb
approve(address,uint256) - 095ea7b3
transferFrom(address,address,uint256) - 23b872dd
```

But for the Reputation token and for some others this technique is not working. Returned code does not have the markers.

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=proxy&action=eth_getCode&address=0x1985365e9f78359a9B6AD760e32412f4a445E862&tag=latest&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

While it is possible to check the balance with `balanceOf` function, even though the function signature `70a08231` is not present in the byte code.
The same situation is for the totalSupply().

https://etherscan.io/token/0x1985365e9f78359a9B6AD760e32412f4a445E862#readContract

Am I missing something or the token is not complying ERC20? Why are not  the markers present in the bytecode?

Comment: What makes you think it would be a fully-compliant ERC20 token?

Comment: Just Etherscan shows ERC20 token, but my point is that possible to call balanceOf function while in the bytecode the 70a08231 signature is not present

Comment: I am also doing this, recognizing supporting interfaces in a contract, but I have chosen another path, I make the `Call()` to the contract, and check its output and error , if it produces an error I flag the contract as non-compliant. Your results prove I have chosen the right way, though I thought of checking for signatures too.

Comment: my current rule to decide if a contract is ERC20 token is: `totalSupply` method exists + `name` method exists + `symbol` method exists + `balanceOf` method exists. Even if they return null values I am still considering them as ERC20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like they actually follow a concept of "Universes", and each universe is an instance of the following:

```
contract Delegator is DelegationTarget {
    function Delegator(IController _controller, bytes32 _controllerLookupName) public {
        controller = _controller;
        controllerLookupName = _controllerLookupName;
    }

    function() external payable {
        // Do nothing if we haven't properly set up the delegator to delegate calls
        if (controllerLookupName == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // Get the delegation target contract
        address _target = controller.lookup(controllerLookupName);

        assembly {
            //0x40 is the address where the next free memory slot is stored in Solidity
            let _calldataMemoryOffset := mload(0x40)
            // new "memory end" including padding. The bitwise operations here ensure we get rounded up to the nearest 32 byte boundary
            let _size := and(add(calldatasize, 0x1f), not(0x1f))
            // Update the pointer at 0x40 to point at new free memory location so any theoretical allocation doesn't stomp our memory in this call
            mstore(0x40, add(_calldataMemoryOffset, _size))
            // Copy method signature and parameters of this call into memory
            calldatacopy(_calldataMemoryOffset, 0x0, calldatasize)
            // Call the actual method via delegation
            let _retval := delegatecall(gas, _target, _calldataMemoryOffset, calldatasize, 0, 0)
            switch _retval
            case 0 {
                // 0 == it threw, so we revert
                revert(0,0)
            } default {
                // If the call succeeded return the return data from the delegate call
                let _returndataMemoryOffset := mload(0x40)
                // Update the pointer at 0x40 again to point at new free memory location so any theoretical allocation doesn't stomp our memory in this call
                mstore(0x40, add(_returndataMemoryOffset, returndatasize))
                returndatacopy(_returndataMemoryOffset, 0x0, returndatasize)
                return(_returndataMemoryOffset, returndatasize)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it is simply a proxy contract that uses delegate call to invoke functions on the address returned by the controller. Your actual functions such as `balanceOf` will be defined on the target contract.